# What is equivalent to GetGlobalResourceObject in Winforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

In web application I used to have a resource file for every page and i used to put two language data (English, Kannada). Ex:

```
Name    Value
ENSave  Save
KNSave  ಉಳಿಸು
```

And while retrieving the value I used `GetGlobalResourceObject`.

```
string Text = GetGlobalResourceObject(resourcename, PrefixLang + "Save").ToString();
```

Here Prefixlang is either KN or EN and based on the prefix lang I was getting the respected value.

Now I am developing a Windows application and I do not want create two resource files for two languages. I want to have a single resource file for both the languages and access it through Prefix Language. I went through so many articles but could not find the solution on how to access resource value by passing resource name and prefix language.

Is there a way to achieve this in Windows Application? Or any better way you may suggest? Thank you.